# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Rich Page Editor doesn't load jQuery Mobile CSS

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

My Rich Page Editor is not loading jQuery Mobile CSS.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

Worklight version: 6.0.0
Eclipse Juno version: 4.2.2

Comment: Please add more information: Worklight version, Eclipse version, are you referring to the Rich Page Editor or the Mobile Test Workbench? Please edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure to follow the training module [explaining how to add jQuery Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSSHE.png) to a Worklight project? It looks like the reference to the CSS may be incorrect.

After following the provided steps to add jQuery Mobile (see link above...), I then:

1. Added a header, a footer and some content.
2. In the Design perspective it looks like this:

[Click for full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSSHE.png)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSSHE.png]

Eclipse Juno SR2 and Worklight 6.0

Comment: Thanks for answering Idan...

Yes, I did training module!

I have other Eclipse with Worklight studio 5 and it work perfectly. before this problem happened, so I installed eclipse and worklight studio again, and everything returned to normal.

Only in this new version the problem occurs, and I dont know why =/

Comment: Ok. Add your HTML to the question as well as a screenshot showing the project tree.

Comment: You can also look at the full size version of the image to see if there are any obvious differences between your project to mine. If you have used the Worklight wizard to create the project, there should be none.

Comment: YEAH, the problem resolved... I dont know why, but I downloaded a new jQuery Mobile file version 1.3 and all returned to normal.